# Cannot get initial-scale to work for windows phone 7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, meta-tags

I have a webbrowser in my winphone 7 app to display a few webpages that contains 2 buttons left and right with a title in the middle, below that a gridview and a few pictures below the gridview.

I tried just about every combination of the following:

```
<!--meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi; width=device-width; initial-scale=0.35; user-scalable=yes" /-->
<!--meta name="mobileoptimized" content="0" /-->
<!--meta name="viewport" content="width=480; initial-scale=5.0; user-scalable=yes;" id="ViewPort" runat="server" />   
<!--meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" /-->   
<!--meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" /-->   
<!--meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /-->
```

If I use device-width the last few columns in my gridview is off screen, trying to scale it properly with initial-scale does nothing.
If I use a set width, for instance 320 or 640, the gridview becomes to small (smaller then the width of the screen), and initial-scale again does nothing.

Any idea's ?

aspx source added :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="iDetailled.aspx.cs" Inherits="iDetailled"  Title="test" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<%@ Register assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<!--meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi; width=device-width; initial-scale=0.35; user-scalable=yes" /-->
<!--meta name="mobileoptimized" content="0" /-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9,user-scalable=yes" id="ViewPort" runat="server" />   
<!--meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" /-->   
<!--meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" /-->   
<!--meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /-->  
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallMe() { javascript: history.go(-1); }
</script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"
     media="screen"/>
<body  class="GradientBackground3" bgcolor="#CFD1D2">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableHistory="True" 
        onnavigate="ScriptManager1_Navigate">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div  align="center">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" 
                onactiveviewchanged="MultiView1_ActiveViewChanged" >
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                <br />
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="90%"   >
                <table align="center"  width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" >
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/min2.png" Height="48px" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" 
                                Width="48px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table align="center" >
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" Text="Turnover by day"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                       </td>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="48px" 
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/plus2.png" onclick="ImageButton2_Click" Width="48px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
                <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDag" ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="Vertical" onrowcreated="GridView2_RowCreated" 
                onselectedindexchanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    onrowdatabound="GridView2_RowDataBound" 
                    EmptyDataText="No data to display" >
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TYBusinessDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM}" 
                        HeaderText="This Year" ReadOnly="True" 
                        SortExpression="TYBusinessDate">
                    <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                        BorderWidth="1px"/>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LYBusinessDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM}" 
                        HeaderText="Last Year" ReadOnly="True" 
                        SortExpression="LYBusinessDate">
                    <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                        BorderWidth="1px"/>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day" HeaderText="Day" ReadOnly="True" 
                        SortExpression="Day">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Bottom" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                        BorderWidth="1px"/>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TYTurnoverAmt" DataFormatString="{0:F0}" 
                        HeaderText="This Year" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TYTurnoverAmt">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Bottom" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                        BorderWidth="1px"/>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LYTurnoverAmt" DataFormatString="{0:F0}" 
                        HeaderText="Last Year" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LYTurnoverAmt">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Bottom" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                        BorderWidth="1px"/>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label55" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" HorizontalAlign="Right" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                        BorderWidth="1px"/>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TYClients" HeaderText="This Year" ReadOnly="True" 
                        SortExpression="TYClients" >
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Bottom" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                        BorderWidth="1px"/>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LYClients" HeaderText="Last Year" ReadOnly="True" 
                        SortExpression="LYClients" >
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Bottom" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                        BorderWidth="1px"/>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/arrow.png" 
                                onclick="ImageButton5_Click" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            </asp:GridView>
                <br />
                <asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDag" BackColor="#CFD1D2" >
                    <Titles>
                        <asp:Title Name="Title1" Text="Turnover">
                        </asp:Title>
                    </Titles>
                    <series>
                        <asp:Series Name="ThisYear" XValueMember="Day" YValueMembers="TYTurnoverAmt" LegendText="Turnover this year">
                        </asp:Series>
                        <asp:Series Name="LastYear" XValueMember="Day" YValueMembers="LYTurnoverAmt" LegendText="Turnover last year">
                        </asp:Series>
                    </series>
                    <chartareas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="true" Area3DStyle-IsClustered="true" BackColor="White" >
                            <AxisY  IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount" IntervalType="Number" IntervalOffsetType="Number"> 
                            </AxisY> 
                            <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" IsClustered="True" />
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </chartareas>
                    <Legends>
                        <asp:Legend Docking="Bottom" Name="Legend1" BackColor="#CFD1D2" >
                        </asp:Legend>
                    </Legends>
                </asp:Chart>
                <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDag" BackColor="#CFD1D2">
                    <Titles>
                        <asp:Title Name="Title1" Text="Clients">
                        </asp:Title>
                    </Titles>
                    <series>
                        <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Legend="Legend1" 
                            Name="ClientTY" XValueMember="Day" YValueMembers="TYClients" BorderWidth="3" LegendText="Clients this year">
                        </asp:Series>
                        <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Legend="Legend1" 
                            Name="ClientLY" XValueMember="Day" YValueMembers="LYClients" BorderWidth="3" LegendText="Clients last year">
                        </asp:Series>
                    </series>
                    <chartareas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" >
                            <AxisY  IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount" IntervalType="Number" IntervalOffsetType="Number"> 
                            </AxisY> 
                            <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="False">
                                <LabelStyle Angle="-90" />
                            </AxisX>
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </chartareas>
                    <Legends>
                        <asp:Legend Docking="Bottom" Name="Legend1" BackColor="#CFD1D2">
                        </asp:Legend>
                    </Legends>
                </asp:Chart>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Back" 
                    Visible="False" />
                <br />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDag" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OSCConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="WWWiPhoneAllStoresPerDay" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </asp:View>

....second view stripped

    </asp:MultiView> 
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you change this to show the generated HTML rather than the server side code please. It will make recreating your situation possible without lots of work.

Comment: How ? its on a windows phone emulator, i can use the internet explorer of that emulator, but it has no button or something to view source. I can use IE on my pc, but then I wouldn't know if the html generated would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The attributes initial-scale, minimum-scale, and maximum-scale are unsupported in WP7. For now, you can only use height, width, and user-scalable. I've found that the blog post Matt linked to has some incorrect/misleading info. See the following for more accurate information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462082%28VS.92%29.aspx

Also, from what I've seen, WP7 needs the separators between attributes to be commas, not semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the page you're trying to display it's hard to say for sure but it sounds like you may have something else on the page affecting the display of the grid.

For reference, the viewport options are documented at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/11/22/the-ie-mobile-viewport-on-windows-phone-7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found the most suitable viewport for mobile windows 7 is:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=${wurfl.getProperty('max_image_width')}; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```